# Does Import-Module work across dot sourcing and other Imported Modules?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am creating a module of helper functions for some tools, all of which use ActiveDirectory in some form. The module full of helper functions is simply a collection of commonly used cmdlets I use in a very specific way.

As of now, all of the modules I have created use ActiveDirectory, including my 'main' script that binds them all together. This doesn't feel like a good choice to make. Is there any way I could import ActiveDirectory once, and have that share all across my modules? Is that even a thing I can do?

The header of my helper functions module

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module AzureAD
Import-Module .\SvD_AD

. (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot 'UI.designer.ps1')
```

The header of my main script

```bsh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module AzureAD
```

Comment: Why is this a concern? If a module is already loaded, PowerShell won't load it again. It's much better to have each module load what it needs, rather than relying on an invisible larger context to supply modules, which means the module can't be used standalone. There is no real redundancy here. If it bothers you enough, you can probably even remove the `Import-Module`s altogether and rely on PowerShell's automatic module loading to get the module when a cmdlet is first used. (I don't recommend this unless a module is only occasionally used and not necessary for all commands.)

Answer (score 0):

When you import a module you load it into your current session. If you have a module that imports other modules, they will find the session in the state when the main module loaded them.
So to answer your question: If your main module imports the official ActiveDirectory-Module once, the following modules have the cmdlets available and don't need to import it themself.